# Pandas selecting timestamp & take values before and after timestamp

Tags: pandas, dataframe, row

I am accessing particular columns in my dataframe as follows:

`df3[(df3['A_TSF'] == 'Spur /') & (df3['A_H'] == '100')].qKfz_1ÜFS`

It gives me a timestamp along with  the entry of column as an output. Timestamp is also the index. For instance:

`2018-01-02 09:18:20   NaN´

How can I access the rows before and after that particular timestamp? Let´s say the last 10 minutes before and after the timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

Pandas allows you to use date ranges with a time index:

```
 df[t-pd.Timedelta('10m'):t]
```

This gives all indexes between t - 10min and t.

In your case:

```
t = df3[(df3['A_TSF'] == 'Spur /') & (df3['A_H'] == '100')].index[0]
result = df.loc[t-pd.Timedelta('10m'):t,'qKfz_1ÜFS']
```

This only works if you know there will only be one row in `df3[(df3['A_TSF'] == 'Spur /') & (df3['A_H'] == '100')]`

Comment: Thanks for your help. With a small alteration it worked.